# Show/hide field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to hide the 'Please specify...' field when I click 'No' after clicking 'Yes'?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var policeInvolvedYes = $('input[name="policeInvolved"][value="yes"]');
        var policeDetailsGroup = $('#policeDetailsGroup');
        var policeDetails = $('#policeDetails');

        function updatePoliceDetailsField() {
            if (policeInvolvedYes.is(':checked')) {
                policeDetailsGroup.show();
                policeDetails.prop('required', true);
            } else {
                policeDetailsGroup.hide();
                policeDetails.prop('required', false);
            }
        }

        policeInvolvedYes.on('change', updatePoliceDetailsField);
        updatePoliceDetailsField();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Were Police/Emergency Services involved?</label>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="policeInvolved" value="yes"> Yes
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="policeInvolved" value="no"> No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div id="policeDetailsGroup" style="display: none;">
            <label for="policeDetails">If yes, please specify:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="policeDetails" name="policeDetails" placeholder="Enter details">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delegate and toggle

```js
$(function() {
  var policeInvolvedYes = $('input[name="policeInvolved"][value="yes"]');
  var policeDetailsGroup = $('#policeDetailsGroup');
  var policeDetails = $('#policeDetails');

  const updatePoliceDetailsField = () => {
    const show = policeInvolvedYes.is(':checked');
    policeDetailsGroup.toggle(show);
    policeDetails.prop('required', show);
  };

  $('.radio').on('change', '[name=policeInvolved]', updatePoliceDetailsField)
  updatePoliceDetailsField()

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Were Police/Emergency Services involved?</label>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="policeInvolved" value="yes"> Yes
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="policeInvolved" value="no"> No
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="policeDetailsGroup" style="display: none;">
  <label>If yes, please specify:
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="policeDetails" name="policeDetails" placeholder="Enter details"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Javascript did the trick - thank you! : )

Answer (score -5):

`$(function() { var policeInvolvedYes = $('input[name="policeInvolved"][value="yes"]'); var policeDetailsGroup = $('#policeDetailsGroup'); var policeDetails = $('#policeDetails');`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.